# Switching power supply reverse driving protection circuit

Tags: buck, switching-regulator, reverse-polarity

I have already "designed" (more like followed the reference design from TI) a buck regulator based on the LM3671 (https://github.com/volium/PowerSupply_lm3671) and I've been very happy with the results, ripple is good for my needs and 600 mA is more than enough for my application (simple MCU/LCD related project).

The design is based on 5v (USB VBUS) to 3.3 volts, see following schematic:

[image: Current LM3671 design without reverse driving protection]

However, I have already killed at least one of the LM3671 I had because I connected the programmer/debugger, which also provides 3.3 volts to the same net, and after looking around I found that indeed, "Absolute Maximum" rating for the SW and FB pins is VIN + 0.2v. (I found that specific piece of information on the Adafruit forum for their LM3671 regulator)

So, with all this in mind, I know I should either:

a. Remove the 3.3V input pin from the programmer

b. Add some circuitry to prevent the main +3.3V net (actually, the SW pin of the LM3671) from seeing the +3.3V provided by the programmer/debugger, based on some FETs?

I know **a)** is the easiest, but not the best option in my opinion, since I'd like to be able to program the parts eventually without having to connect the main power supply (via USB). And **b)**, well, I really don't know how to implement **b)**.

I really really appreciate the help.

Comment: I take it the USB port is *not* connected when you plug the programmer in?

Comment: Also, is there stuff on the Vcc rail in your design?

Comment: Yes, I think the main issue happens when the main USB port is not connected, (because the rule outlined above, "SW and FB pins is VIN + 0.2v" is being violated); however,  I would like to be able to have both of the connected when I'm debugging, so that I don't have to connect/unconnect the main USB. Also, this current design does have a single RGB LED hanging off the VCC rail, but I wouldn't expect (or care) that to be functional while the main MCU is being programmed. I think I can treat this as a parallel power supply, I just don't know how to do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### Reverse protection for regulators is easier than it sounds, but USB makes it harder

Fortunately, your problem (your regulator not liking being backpowered with its input off) is actually easy to solve, albeit not as easy as it initially looks.  On first guess, you'd think a diode from output to input of the regulator would solve the problem, and you're *almost* right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faby6K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, the fact we're dealing with a USB-powered device makes this a bit harder.  You see, one of the many rules in the USB specification is that devices shall *never* backfeed power onto their "upstream" USB connection.  In fact, some USB hosts [can be damaged or confused by backfeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh6iKilgtG0).

So, we need to toss another diode in to make sure that nothing bad happens to a turned-off USB host if the board is being powered by the programming dongle:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzhs53.png)</sup>

With the extra diode in there, now the regulator is safe from being powered up "backwards" *and* powering it up "backwards" won't backfeed the USB port, either.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed answer, and taking the time to explain things so thoroughly. I will probably go and implement your circuit, but I'll also take a look at ideal diodes like @next-hack suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an "ideal diode"/or-ing FET controller or an hot-swap IC between the output of your switching IC and the 3.3 signal on the connector. They tyipically feature reverse current protection and low voltage drop.

As an example (I didn't look at the specs of your system):
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps25200.pdf

There are many other (just search for "hot swap" or "ideal diode" on mouser or digikey) that will for sure suit your needs.

EDITs: 
Of course, if using TPS25200, you must connect the EN signal to the USB 5V. Remember also to put a resistor between 5V and gnd to discharge the input capacitor.

Comment: I wouldn't do this actually -- its more cost for no gain, and a potential to lose due to the Vcc domain being off while the 3v3 domain is on.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer a solution, I'll start looking into the tps25200 and I'll report back.